# Map Iterator working for begin() but not for rbegin()

Tags: c++, list, pointers, dictionary, iterator

I have some class called Order. For some reason, the following code won't compile while using rbegin(), but it works for begin(). Is there a problem in the way I'm declaring the iterator or perhaps a problem with my pointer reference?

```
map<double, list<Order*>> m
typedef map<double, list<Order*>>::iterator iter;
iter iterator;

iterator = m.rbegin(); // this only works for m.begin()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rbegin()` returns a `reverse_iterator`, not an `iterator`.

Comment: Indeed. If using C++11, you can try `auto it = m.rbegin();`

Answer (score 2):

The types returned from `begin()` and `rbegin()` are different:

- `begin()` returns `std::map<K, V>::iterator`
- `rbegin()` returns `std::reverse_iterator<std::map<K, V>::iterator>`

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea. Thanks!